# Tensor product of modules and vector spaces

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $K$ be a field, $K[t]$ be a polynomial ring and be $K(t)$ be the fraction field of $K[t]$. We take the $K[t]$-module $K[t]/(t) \otimes_{K} K(t)$ with the action $r(t)\left(\overline{p(t)} \otimes \frac{q(t)}{h(t)}\right)= \overline{r(t)q(t)}\otimes \frac{q(t)}{h(t)}$.

Is it possible to simplify $K[t]/(t) \otimes_{K} K(t)$ as $K[t]$-module with the given operation?

I want that $K[t]/(t) \otimes_{K} K(t)$ is isomorphic to  $K[t]/(t) \otimes_{K} K(t)$ as $K[t]$-module with the action on $K(t)$. But, I know that this in general is false, and this case is false as well.

Comment: $K[t]/(t) \otimes_{K} K(t)$ is isomorphic to itself. Maybe you want to say something else in the third paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

$K[t]/(t)$ is isomorphic as $K$-module to $K$, so $K[t]/(t)\otimes_KK(t)\cong K\otimes_KK(t)\cong K(t)$ as $K$-modules. What's the $K[t]$-operation on $K[t]/(t)\cong K$? A polynomial acts by multiplication with its constant term. Thus, what's the $K[t]$-operation on $K[t]/(t)\otimes_KK(t)\cong K(t)$? A polynomial acts by multiplication with its constant term (with respect to the usual $K$-module structure on $K(t)$). This is never the same as the usual $K[t]$-operation on $K(t)$.

Comment: This does not answer my questión. You did write the same than my above comment.

Comment: @WagnerBadilla Are you expecting something even simpler than $K(t)$ with an explicit description of the operation? I don't think that's reasonable.

Comment: @WágnerBadilla i think it answers your question quite well. Maybe you meant to ask a different question?